# MATLAB: Remove semicolon from all matrix elements

Tags: matlab

I am reading a .txt file, and when it reads in to matlab, I get my proper vectors and everything, except they have a semicolon at the end of each number. Now, I'm not sure if it's better to correct this error while I read the file, or if I can just quickly correct it with some code after I've read in my files. Unfortunately, I don't know how to fix it either way. I'm doing something like this.

```
for i = 1:100000
    try
        disp(strcat('ToF_ROI_XYZcoordinates_', num2str(i), '.txt'));
        ToF_File_ID = fopen(strcat('ToF_ROI_XYZcoordinates_', num2str(i), '.txt'));
        ToF_XYZ_Coordinates(i,:) = textscan(ToF_File_ID,'%s %s %s');
        fclose(ToF_File_ID);

        disp(strcat('Navi_Endo_RefOrient_', num2str(i), '.txt'))
        Navi_Orient_File_ID = fopen(strcat('Navi_Endo_RefOrient_', num2str(i), '.txt'));
        Navi_Endo_RefOrient(i,:) = textscan(Navi_Orient_File_ID,'%s');
        fclose(Navi_Orient_File_ID);

        disp(strcat('Navi_Endo_RefOffsetPosVec_', num2str(i), '.txt'))
        Navi_Offset_File_ID = fopen(strcat('Navi_Endo_RefOffsetPosVec_', num2str(i), '.txt'));
        Navi_Endo_RefOffsetPosVec(i,:) = textscan(Navi_Offset_File_ID,'%s');
        fclose(Navi_Offset_File_ID);

    catch err
        break
    end
end
```

EDIT: My matrix looks something like this if you're confused

```
[ 1; 2; 3; 4; ]
| 5; 6; 7; 8; |
| 9; 1; 2; 3; |
[ 4; 5; 6; 7; ]
```

and I want it like this

```
[ 1 2 3 4 ]
| 5 6 7 8 |
| 9 1 2 3 |
[ 4 5 6 7 ]
```

Any help in removing those semicolons from my new variables would be great, thanks!

Comment: Can you do transpose of matrix A=A' ?

Comment: Umm... I think you misinterpreted my matrix. The semi-colons are not an input, they are an output. So they are a string within the matrix. I need to remove that string entirely. Transposing will just put it somewhere else and each matrix element will still have it inside.

Comment: What is example content of `ToF_ROI_XYZcoordinates_`, `ToF_ROI_XYZcoordinates_` and `Navi_Endo_RefOffsetPosVec_` .txt files?

Comment: The matrix I posted towards the bottom is what matlab extracts from the .txt files...I thought that should be enough information. The text files are basically exactly what my matrices are showing, except formatted in a .txt file (so obviously it doesn't have the brackets, just the numbers and semi-colons)

Comment: @JohnDodson So why not used [dlmread](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/dlmread.html) to read the matrices?

Comment: Why don't you specify the semicolon in the format string and then read in integer values like this: `'%d; %d; %d;'`?

Comment: You can use `regexprep` or `strrep` to replace `';'` with `''`

Comment: @H.Muster Thanks! That worked perfectly =), very easy fix

Comment: @Marcin Also a good fix that works, although textscan works a little better for my purposes

Comment: @Mohsen And yet again, that also works. I learned 3 new things here =p. Using that is a little more crude for my example I think, but definitely useful for many applications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are still some things unclear, but suppose you generate the matrix with this piece of code:

```
textscan(ToF_File_ID,'%s %s %s')
```

If you want to parse this to get rid of semicolumns, you can change it into this:

```
strrep(textscan(ToF_File_ID,'%s %s %s'), ';', '')
```

Comment: I am not sure whether `strrep` already exists for a long time, if your version does not support it try replacing it with `regexprep`

Comment: You could also use just `textscan` with the `delimiter` option, removing the need for `strrep`: `textscan(ToF_File_ID, '%s %s %s', 'delimiter', {'', ';'})`